# Strange behavior of string format in python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format

Working with svn logs in xml format i've accidentally got an error in my script.
Error message is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

By debugging input data i have found what was wrong. Here is an example:

```
a=u'\u0440\u0435\u044c\u0434\u0437\u0444\u043a\u044b\u0443\u043a \u043c\u0443\u043a\u044b\u0448\u0449\u0442 \u0430\u0448\u0447'
>>> print a
реьдзфкыук мукышщт ашч
>>> print '{}'.format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can you please explain what is wrong with format? 
Seems like it sees **u** before string bytes and try to decode it from UTF8.
However in Python 3 above example works without error.

Comment: Python 3 strings are the same thing as Python 2 unicode objects, which are represented as `u"..."` values here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Unicode and byte string values. Use a *unicode* format:

```
print u'{}'.format(a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a=u'\u0440\u0435\u044c\u0434\u0437\u0444\u043a\u044b\u0443\u043a \u043c\u0443\u043a\u044b\u0448\u0449\u0442 \u0430\u0448\u0447'
>>> print u'{}'.format(a)
реьдзфкыук мукышщт ашч
```

In Python 3, strings are unicode values by default; in Python 2, `u"..."` indicates a unicode value and regular strings (`"..."`) are *byte* strings.

Mixing a byte strings and unicode value results in automatic encoding or decoding with the default codec (ASCII), and that's what happens here. The `str.format()` method has to encode the Unicode value to a byte string to interpolate.

Comment: If i use:
        print '%s' % (a)
it prints without errors, only format gives an error. Can you please provide any else example that will give following error?

Comment: the `%` format parameter then coerces the string format to Unicode; that's equally problematic (another implicit conversion) and this happens to work because your format only has ASCII bytes in it. There are many other problematic situations; concat unicode and encoded bytes will also lead to implicit conversions.